# Unable to use Piccaso in Fragments

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, picasso, image-loading

Here's my code where I've got error in

```
Picasso.with(ThreeFragement.this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
```

even if I'm setting `ThreeFragment` to getContext, it is not working.

The whole code is written below where in i want to implement Picasso to  Firebase `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment` and retrieve images over it.

This was just a tutorial implemented on an `Activity` which I tried putting in `Fragment`.

```
package com.tabs.ayushmaniac.letsmanageit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tabs.ayushmaniac.letsmanageit.fragment.AddMovieFragment;
import com.tabs.ayushmaniac.letsmanageit.models.Movie;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ThreeFragment  extends Fragment {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    ScaleAnimation shrinkAnim;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private TextView tvNoMovies;

    //Getting reference to Firebase Database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = database.getReference();

    private static final String USER_ID = "53";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
        return rootView;

        //Initializing our Recyclerview
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        tvNoMovies = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_no_movies);

        //scale animation to shrink floating actionbar
        shrinkAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.15f, 0f, 1.15f, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            //to enable optimization of recyclerview
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
        //using staggered grid pattern in recyclerview
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        //Say Hello to our new Firebase UI Element, i.e., FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Movie,MovieViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Movie, MovieViewHolder>(
                Movie.class,
                R.layout.movie_board_item,
                MovieViewHolder.class,
                //referencing the node where we want the database to store the data from our Object
                mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(USER_ID).child("movies").getRef()
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MovieViewHolder viewHolder, Movie model, int position) {
                if(tvNoMovies.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
                    tvNoMovies.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                viewHolder.tvMovieName.setText(model.getMovieName());
                viewHolder.ratingBar.setRating(model.getMovieRating());
                Picasso.with(this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        fab = (FloatingActionButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, new AddMovieFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                //animation being used to make floating actionbar disappear
                shrinkAnim.setDuration(400);
                fab.setAnimation(shrinkAnim);
                shrinkAnim.start();
                shrinkAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        //changing floating actionbar visibility to gone on animation end
                        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }




    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvMovieName;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
        ImageView ivMoviePoster;

        public MovieViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvMovieName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
            ivMoviePoster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_movie_poster);
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `ThreeFragement.this`

Try below code;

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
```

Comment: works here but it is not letting recylerview be a reachable statement.
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

Comment: @AyushShrivastava you have `return rootView;` just after  `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);`. You should have return statement at the end of the method

Comment: Dear use rootView intead of getView()

Comment: i got a red line mark in rootView now lmao :( is there any tip?

Comment: yuupp got it.....You have to use   return rootView; at the and of onCreateView() function

Comment: red line will be gone

Comment: using it on the end itself sir, still it is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155381/discussion-between-vishal-vaishnav-and-ayush-shrivastava).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
```

instead of

```
Picasso.with(ThreeFragement.this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
```

Comment: use... rootview mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActivity()`, which returns the `activity` associated with a fragment.

So replace code

```
Picasso.with(ThreeFragement.this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
```

**with**

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
```